# Sum all the array that it`s generated from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that gives me how much I spent on the month, I need to sum all the expenses that I had I'm tring to use the sum() function in python but it`s giving me this error :

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/Projeto automacao financeira/pdf.py", line 82, in <module>
a.analyzePdf("Document.pdf")
File "C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/Projeto automacao financeira/pdf.py", line 61, in analyzePdf
print("Sum of elements in given list is :", sum(object))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

What should I do? I already converted from str to float, but I still don`t the expected result, here`s the code:

```
class BankAccountReport():

    def __init__(self):
        self.IV_total_spent = 0.0
        self.IV_current_funds = 0.0
        self.IV_expenses = {"Day of the month": {}, "Business Expenses": {}, "Transaction ID": {}, "location": "", "cost": 0.0,"personal": ""}
        self.IV_deposits = {"Day of the month": {}, "Transaction ID": {}, "location": "", "cost": 0.0}
        self.IV_expense_filters = {"Business": {}, "Random": {}, "Search_string": "","Search_type": 0, "Personal": {}}

    def analyzePdf(self, pdf_file=None):
        call_result = {}
        debug_data = []
        return_msg = "BankAccountReport:analyzePdf"
        date = ""
        if type(pdf_file) != str:
            return_msg += "input validation failed: pdf_file must be an string that sets where the document is"
            return {{'success': RC.input_validation_failed, 'return_msg': return_msg, 'debug_data': debug_data}}
        if type(date) != str:
            return_msg += "You shouldn`t put "" in the date you are setting to"
            return {{'success': RC.input_validation_failed, 'return_msg': return_msg, 'debug_data': debug_data}}

        df = wrapper.read_pdf(pdf_file, pages= "all", output_format="csv")
        df = df.fillna("0")
        df.to_csv("output.csv")
        df = pd.read_csv("output.csv", usecols=['Data', "Docto.", "Débito (R$)", "Saldo (R$)"])


        df.to_csv("output2.csv")
        #print(df)
        extract = pd.read_csv('output2.csv')
        date = input("what date do you want?")
        date_filter = (extract["Data"] == date)
        filtered_dates = extract[date_filter]
        #print(filtered_dates.head())

        data = pd.read_csv("output2.csv", usecols= ["Saldo (R$)"] )
        data1 = pd.read_csv("output2.csv", usecols=['Débito (R$)'])
        print(data)

        names = data.values.tolist()
        names1= data1.values.tolist()
        print(names1)
        print(names)

        numbers = df['Saldo (R$)'].str.split().str[1].str.replace(',', '.').apply(float)
        numbers1 = df["Débito (R$)"].str.split().str[1].str.replace(",", ".").apply(float)

        numbers = numbers.fillna("0")
        numbers1 = numbers.fillna("0")
        for object in numbers1:
            print(object)
            print("Sum of elements in given list is :", sum(object))
```

Comment: `object` is a number. What do you think is `sum(object)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of redundant information, and also a lot of missing information in your question. In particular, we do not know the data types of the columns in `numbers1`. I *guess* you want to add all rows, and the items are originally represented as strings. Convert them to floats and sum up:

```
numbers1.astype(float).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting this error because `df['Saldo (R$)'].str` will not return pandas series.

Probably you need to write your own function such as

```
def toNumber(str):
    return float(str.split().str[1].str.replace(',', '.'))
```

and in the code you can write

```
numbers = df['Saldo (R$)'].apply(toNumber)
```

Comment: but I have the same error that if I use just the "Débito (R$)" that is using a data frame